# C# BitConverter

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Here is my code. It gives an error. Why?

I want to convert `byte[]` to `sbyte[]`. Is there a simple alternative?

```
byte[] final = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(contentBArr);

sbyte[] vOut = new sbyte[final.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < final.Length; i++)
{
    var tmp = BitConverter.ToChar(final, i);
    vOut[i] = (sbyte)tmp;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use BitConverter.ToChar method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tochar(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: i have edited my question. To convert unsigned byte array to signed byte array

Comment: Note: `i < final.Length - 1` should just be: `i < final.Length`.  (`<` vs `<=` takes care of the `-1`)  Not that you should have a variable named `final`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to convert byte[] to sbyte[]. Is there a simple alternative?

LINQ approach:

```
var input = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var output = input.Select(x => (sbyte)x).ToArray();
```

You can do the same using simple `for` loop:

```
var input = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var output = new sbyte[input.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    output[i] = (sbyte)input[i];
}
```

Comment: LINQ is good for me. Thanks a lot. for correcting my question. and for answer

Comment: `output[i] = (sbyte)input[i];` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Convert.ToSByte() method the same as this,

```
byte[] final = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(contentBArr);

sbyte[] vOut = new sbyte[final.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < final.Length - 1; i++)
{
    var tmp = Convert.ToSByte(final[i]);
    vOut[i] = (sbyte)tmp;
}
```

Another example:

```
byte[] numbers = { Byte.MinValue, 10, 100, Byte.MaxValue };
sbyte result;

foreach (byte number in numbers)
{
   try {
      result = Convert.ToSByte(number);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value {1} to the {2} value {3}.",
                        number.GetType().Name, number,
                        result.GetType().Name, result);
   }
   catch (OverflowException) {
      Console.WriteLine("The {0} value {1} is outside the range of the SByte type.",
                        number.GetType().Name, number);
   }
}
```

References: *[Convert.ToSByte Method (Byte)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a7yfs6t2(v=vs.100).aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: I can't see `Convert.ToSByte` overload for `byte[]` and `int` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast this way:

```
byte[] final = new byte[] { 0, 5, 130, 255 };
sbyte[] vOut = final.Select(b => (sbyte)b).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vOut)); // 0, 5, -126, -1
```

Comment: you have used variable names as me. Thanks a lot

Comment: For what it's worth, I would use `Array.ConvertAll(final, b => (sbyte) b)` instead of the LINQ methods here. Array.ConvertAll will be able to allocate the full array ahead of time, thereby avoiding any reallocations during the conversion.

Comment: Hm, good thought @Michael. However, I'm going to leave my answer using LINQ for a couple of reasons: 1. this is a hash, thus just a few bytes, thus performance isn't likely a concern, 2. I generally like using a standardized language (LINQ) for all enumerables, instead of needing to read and write different syntaxes for arrays, `List<T>`s, and other collections.